# How to set the Dropdown value in Sencha Ext JS 4.2

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have JSON String

> [{"firstName" : "John", "lastName" : "Smith"}]

How to set the value in Dropdown. I tried setValue() but Dropdown dispays all json objects.

Please help me, I am using Sencha Ext JS 4.2

Answer (score 0):

You have to first extract the string from the record that you want to set in combo like this:

```
    combo.setValue(record.get("firstname") + " " + record.get("lastname"));
```